# Why can't fmt::Arguments be safely generated at runtime?

Tags: rust

The documentation for [`core::fmt::Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) states:

> This structure represents a safely precompiled version of a format string and its arguments. This cannot be generated at runtime because it cannot safely be done, so no constructors are given and the fields are private to prevent modification.

Exactly what is it about generating such a structure at runtime that cannot safely be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think that this sentence is a bit misleading. You can create a value of `Arguments` at runtime using `format_args!`. What you cannot do is to build an `Arguments` using an arbitary string format expression.

This is because the main invarants hold in `Arguments` are:

1. Every placeholder has an argument.
2. Every argument is used at least once.
3. Every argument implements the proper trait that every argument implements the proper trait.

For example, if your string format is `"{0}{1:?}{2:x}{2:X}"` then you must have three arguments: the first one must implement `Display`, the second one `Debug` and the third one `LowerHex + UpperHex`.

You could create an API to build an `Arguments` in runtime with such invariants, but not by using a non-const format string. Because how would you know what traits to require? And what is the point of that? If you want to format your objects not using a string format, there is no reason to require an `Arguments` in the first place.

By requiring that the string is a literal, the macro `format_args!` can check during compile time that the arguments implement the proper traits.

Comment: Thank you—this makes perfect sense.  As for “what is the point of that?”: I would like to format an object using a string format that has been supplied to my proc macro, so is in token form—I can stringify the tokens but of course I cannot use them in `format!` (nor can this particular macro output a `format!` invocation).

Comment: @eggyal: Ah, macros with `format!` are tricky. But sometimes they can be done, if you can convince the compiler that your macro always emits correct code, as in this [toy playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f8cb6294c401237dbb6cfb7594e26c4d). Maybe you could open a question about that?

Comment: But that requires the macro to expand to a `format!` invocation, which mine cannot do (it is invoked in item position).